# retrieve keystroke that triggered function on Qt

Tags: qt, shortcut

I'm adding a list of shortcuts (keys 0-9) to some action `selectOverlay` on qt. How can I retrieve which keystroke triggered the slot on `selectOverlay()`?

```
connect( selectOverlay, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(selectOverlay()) );
```

Comment: You can't. What's your use case?

Comment: @Frank there might be up to 9 layers on an image and I'd like the user to be able to select each of them by keystroke. FYI I created 9 actions, one for each keystroke and put the value on the data field. That way at least I don't have to repeat the code of the triggered function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnt try, but.

On slot you can call

```
QObject::sender()
```

To get a pointer to the object that lauched the signal.

Then you can cast the pointer to a QShorcut or a QShorcutEvent

and query the key with   [key()](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qshortcut.html#key-prop)

In case its a qaction, you can fill the data()  of it with the key when you create it and ask for it after the proper cast in the slot.

Just try which case works for you.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a good example on when to use the `QSignalMapper` class.